# How exactly are Molecular Manipulation and Reality Manipulation different?

Tags: comics, powers

On the surface, Molecular control and Reality manipulation do essentially the same thing: alter physical elements and environments on a fundamental level, essentially doing with them whatsoever the user chooses. At it's base, I think molecular control is just a bit more bound by the laws of physics, to a degree. To be fair, though, this isn't "strictly" true, and can vary by depiction. In Marvel comics, the **Beyonder** is an extra-dimensional being shown to be able to control reality, warp, and pop in and out of reality...

[image]

Concurrently, the **Molecule Man** is a human with total control over *all* molecules and corresponding energies. He's so powerful that he's been shown able to affect even *magical* items, like Thor's Hammer, with less than a gesture...

[image]

At times, both have been shown to be near *equal* in power though.

[image]

[image]

To be fair, this simply could have been done for plot purposes.

On a whole new spectrum, in DC comics, you have characters like **Dr. Manhattan** who have shown an aptitude for *both* abilities, having started out human and gaining powers of molecular manipulation, then learning control over energy, then having the ability to see the world "beyond time", and then alter "pull strings in" differing realities.

[image]

Neil Gaiman's **Dream/Sandman** is said to have the Reality form of the power, as well, though its more a function of *what* he is in terms of concept, than an out an out "ability" he uses...

[image]

Can someone please elaborate on the specifics of each, how they differ in the particulars, and give examples of skilled users in both utilizing the abilities so that precise differences can be measured?

Examples from other comics and media can be shown.

Comment: Is this not significantly too broad, since it asks for examples across all media?

Comment: Anyway, like the answer says, it's completely dependent on how the writers want to characterize it. They are two words for what might just be called miracles in a work with a different tone. If the writers want to sound a little sciency, they talk about reality, if they want to sound more sciency it's molecules. If they really want to pile on the science, it will be quantum manipulation, or there will be some computer jargon with administrators and kernels and such.

Comment: @Adamant Considering the range, I think I had to leave it open for examples. For some reason, the silent inference is that "Reality" goes beyond the mere _physics,_ in so much as doing things that are outright _implausible,_ such as combining a man and a car inot a literal living, breathing machine, _somehow_ without killing him. Molecular control _could_ merge them, but the laws of physics would mean the organic and inorganic material couldn't "fuse", but more exist side by side.

Answer (score 3):

Molecule Man's powers have been changed over time so that he is also a reality warper on  the level of the Beyonder, and that his original limitations (he couldn't originally effect organic molecules, for example, conveniently explaining why he simply couldn't wave his hand and insta-kill his opponents) were simply a mental block he'd imposed on himself. He's said he only keeps the name because he thinks the alliteration is cool.

In other words, there is no difference that can be defined objectively. It's all up to what the writers want it to be.

Comment: Okay... "No difference objectively" is fine. And thank you for the information about his mental block. But as you have stated; his powers have _changed_ over time, so he is essentially, a reality warper. Even **SleepWalker** can "warp" reality, but that's essentially _damaging_ it; this happened to Deathlok when he was caught in the beam, and his cybernetics registered it as "systems damage." In contrast, Beyonder and MM have been shown to actually be able to **Reshape it to their wills** with nary any negative effects.